# ruby unpack for 64-bit integer

Tags: ruby, binary

I need to convert `big-endian, 8-bytes, uint64` into an integer.

I can only find `Q` in the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:unpack) for `64-bit unsigned, native endian (uint64_t)` and nothing for `64-bit big-endian uint64`.

So I just want to make sure that `Q` is the right one to use since Q does not specify that it is for `big-endian`

What I'm using: `uid = io.read(8).unpack("Q")[0]`

Or should I break it down into 2 32-bit integers then convert to string then concatenate like ...

`uid = (io.read(4).unpack("N")[0].to_s + io.read(4).unpack("N")[0].to_s).to_i`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". What did you try? Did the code break? If so, where's the code and explanation showing where it broke.

Comment: So you [checked the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) and tested with data of a known quantity to verify it worked out?

Comment: @theTinMan I added code examples. Q doesn't specify that it's for a big-endian so that is what concerns me. Should I use Q or should I break the number into 2 numbers then concatenate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the same documentation page you linked:

> ```
> S> L> Q>  | Integer | same as the directives without ">" except
> s> l> q>  |         | big endian
> ```